# ASP.net webpages for multi Language support in caption texts

Tags: asp.net

I am new for the ASP.net.
I have to build the web pages that will support Marathi language captions.
I am using DIV tag for viewing the text in English in .aspx file. Now these text is need to be replaced by Marathi text.

Please guide how can i do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource files (.resx) may help you. Store all texts in resource files, and categorize them for each language (for instance, on folder for each language).

Suppose you have a folder "en" and in that folder a resource file "myResourceFile.resx". Then you can read them as follows:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("en/myResourceFile", "myDivText");
```

Comment: Yes, i have created resource file (MultiLanguage.mr-IN.resx) and In that i have one entry with Name:GetReport with the corresponding value..  NOw following is the code in my .aspx file "<div class="row1_basicinfo_L">
                                Address of building:
                            </div>" So how can i get this done. Thanks...

Comment: One way is to do like:

<div><%=HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MultiLanguage.mr-IN.resx","GetReport");%></div>

And the other way is to give the runat="server" and id="myDiv" attributes, and in the code behind:
myDiv.innerHtml = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MultiLanguage.mr-IN.resx","GetReport");